# Confused on storing sets, reps, & comment for react native workout app

Tags: react-native

I can't seem to wrap my head around this but I'm building a workout tracking out app and I want to log sets, reps, and comment for each set. I'm confused as how to even go by this as these are 3 different values but they need to be linked together as they are related to one another & each set needs to have a unique ID as it is different but still needs to be linked to it's reps & comment which needs to be linked to it's workout so later on it can be called upon as a reference.

I know this is noobie question but I'm genuinely confused and can't wrap my head around it no matter on how much I google it.

Comment: what database u are using

Comment: Nothing? It's a simple react native app that I've just started. Or whatever that comes with basic RN install.

Comment: From my research I think I need to use prop for this but I don't know how to assign 3 different things to one prop. If that makes sense. because each prop would need to have a unique key value and then they would hold a weight, reps, and then comment for that prop. Any tips/input would be appreciated.